# use service to get json data

Tags: angularjs, json

I want to create a service that get a `json` data.

**controller :**

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('serviceCtrl',['$scope', 'Services', function($scope,Services) {
      $scope.title="services";
      $scope.services = Services.get();
}]);
```

**factory service :**

```
angular.module('app')
        .factory('Services', function(){
            return $http.get('/api/services.json').then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            })
        });
```

**service.html :**

```
<div ng-repeat="service in Services">
    <div class=" thumbnail-services col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
        <figure class="figure">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" alt="{{Services.name}}">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption">
            <a href="">
                <h3>{{Services.name}}</h3>
            </a>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

but i am getting an error `ReferenceError: $http is not defined`

is it right the way i create the factory ?

Answer (score 1):

$http is part of angular and you need to inject it into your factory before you can use it. Moreover you do not want to return a promise, but an object which has the functionality you need.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Services', myService);

    myService.$inject = ['$http'];

    function myService($http){
        function getJson() {
            return $http.get('/api/services.json').then(function(response){
                return response.data;
            })
        }

        return {
          getJson: getJson
        };
    }
```

Afterwards you can use this service in your controller.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('serviceCtrl', serviceCtrl);

    serviceCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'Services'];

    function serviceCtrl($scope,Services){
        var vm = this;
        this.json = {}

        activate();

        function activate(){
            Services.getJson().then(function(response){
                vm.json = response;
            });
        }
    }
```

Note that it is better to resolve promises before you actually load the state.

Comment: but it still give me output angular.js:14110 TypeError: Services.get is not a function.

Comment: @vandi that is because he named it to `.getJson()` instead of `.get()`. Don't just copy paste the code, try to read and understand the concepts.